# is_displayed() returns false even if the element is visible for selenium webdriver 2.42 IE 11

Tags: selenium

I am trying to upload a file with element.send_keys() and this works with FF and Chrome, but when I tried the same script with IE 11, the upload failed with the following error:

```
ul.send_keys(license_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 293, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not displayed'
```

When I tried to debug, I get element.is_displayed() as false.

I tried to set value of element object to filepath with:

```
 driver.execute_script(("var v=document.getElementById(<id>);v.setAttribute('value', '<filepath>')
```

but even the above didn't work.

I tried ActionChains for the same, but that also didn't work.

I always get "Element is not displayed" error.

```
IE version: 11.0
Selenium Webdriver: 2.42
Windows 8
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: No, I haven't figured it out yet, I am not running that particular test with IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the opacity of your element before sending the keys. Internet Explorer, particularly with IEDriverServer, is sensitive to invisible elements and won't send keys until it can see it.

This will tell Selenium to use JS to show the element before trying to send keys to it, which fixed the issue for me in Python:

```
file_input = webdriver.find_element_by_id("thing")
webdriver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.opacity = '1';", file_input)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think IE 11 supports good with windows 8.1 and tablet version of windows 8.1 os, because IE 11 has been designed specifically for tablet version of windows that too for the version 8.1.

IE11 works on windows 7, windows server 2008 r2, windows 8.1, windows server 2012 r2.

That might be the reason which causing trouble in finding element using selenium.

I don't know much but try to run with IE10 once.